# Pass a javascript variable to php

Tags: php, javascript

Newb question so excuse me if there's an obvious answer (I've tried everything I can think of).

I have a javascript variable setup like so:

```
var imageURL = <?php echo json_encode($imageRows[0]['URL_Path']); ?>;
```

Where $imageRows[0] can be an integer from 0 to whatever.

I also have another variable like so:

```
var count = 15
```

I need to pass the count into the imageURL variable... can this be done?

I guessed something like:

```
 var imageURL = <?php echo json_encode($imageRows['count']['URL_Path']); ?>;

 var imageURL = <?php echo json_encode($imageRows[(count)]['URL_Path']); ?>;
```

etc but nothings working.

Thanks

Edit:
Answered by Mike Brant.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "pass the count into the imageURL variable"?  These are both javascript variables, what does PHP have to do with it other than the imageURL variable being created by PHP?

Comment: You'd have to send the variable in the headers somewhere (ex. as a cookie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just `json_encode()` the entire `$imageRows` variable.  Then you have free access to it in javascript.  Like this:

```
var image_urls = <?php echo json_encode($imageRows); ?>;
var count = 15;
var the_url_you_want = image_urls[count]['URL_PATH'];
```

Comment: This is great... works like a champ :) Took me a while to test it out.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

I understand your question better now. It looks like you're trying to get PHP to respond to a variable in your Javascript and echo the output. You can put the count into the querystring (`http://server/yourpage.php?count=15`) and then get the `count` variable into your php like so: `$_GET['count']`

Edit: From your comment it looks like you actually DO have this count as a PHP variable (a return from MYSQL). Your difficulty may come from PHP's interpretation of string interpolation. It sees the `[]` after `$imageRows` as part of the PHP expression, and you seem to want to pass count as a javascript variable. You could do `$imageRows[$count]` if you already have a `$count` PHP variable. If you must have it as a javascript variable, you can do `var count = <?php echo $count?>;` and then echo the JSON of all `{$imageRows}`, accessing in javascript with `count`.

(Previously: Why can't you just use `$count` ?)

Comment: Can you use $count inside a Script tag?

Comment: +1for edit ans answer ;)

Comment: @user1399098 You could if it were a PHP variable, although now I know that's now what you were asking.

Answer (score 1):

Not the way you are thinking about it but you could always perform an AJAX request when the page loads which would allow you to pass both variables to PHP (or any web server) as standard request parameters.

See [jQuery#ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) as an example.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'example.php',
  data: {
    count: count
  },
  success: function(data) {
    // Do something with the data
  }
});
```

The above is a very rough example however.

Answer (score 0):

(editing because you changed the question so that I understand it better)

PHP won't be able to read the value of a JavaScript variable on the browser's end, you'll have to pass it in to the page as a POST variable or in a cookie.

Comment: The count isn't based on a url number its the count from a mySQL row.